# APEX - Setting a CSS class based on a page item rather than a static value?

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I'd like to set either the CSS class or an attribute of a region based on the value of a page item. I've tried the following syntax with no real joy:

```
#P0_CURRENT_SCHEMA#
:P0_CURRENT_SCHEMA
&P0_CURRENT_SCHEMA
```

Is there a syntax that will allow me to use the value of a page item rather than a static value to set the value of a CSS class (my aim here is to have part of the UI colour code itself based on what environment it is in).

Comment: The syntax to be used depends of the execution context, the first one is for html substitution, the second one is a bind in a plsql block and the third one (you're missing a final dot) is a value reference used mostly in url parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your substitution syntax isn't quite right. You need the period at the end.

```
&P0_CURRENT_SCHEMA.
```

A jQuery approach that would allow for dynamic changing of the class on the fly. It could be added to a dynamic action.

```
$('#P0_SET_MY_CLASS').addClass($('#P0_CURRENT_SCHEMA').val());
```